# How to get requests path with unresolved variables in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-kotlin

I'm trying to get the request's path with unresolved path variables in a WebFilter. I know in SpringBoot Servlet version it is possible to do this by getting request's attribute with key [`org.springframework.web.servlet.View.pathVariables`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html#PATH_VARIABLES). Although it seems no attribute is populated in WebFlux regarding that. Is there anyway to do this in a filter?

Answer (score 0):

WebFlux version of [`org.springframework.web.servlet.View.pathVariables`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html#PATH_VARIABLES) is [`org.springframework.web.reactive.HandlerMapping.bestMatchingPattern`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/HandlerMapping.html#BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE).

We can obtain it by doing

```kotlin
exchange.attributes[HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE]
```